# How to create a custom filter tag for a Django object?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter, django-template-filters, django-filters

I have a model called Profile.
I want to create a custom filter tag based on this idea: Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Then I can use this filter within the template.
Just complete this function:
`

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()
from ..models import Profile
@register......
def filter_profile():
    ....
```

Then how to use it from the template.

And thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show items that belong to the current user, you can do:

```html
{% if user == request.user%}
  <!-- Do something -->
{% endif %}
```

This will show only items that are related to the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the Profile model with a user one-to-one field (which is the most likely scenario) you would not need to create such a filter at all. You can access related models in the template directly. Here's an example:

model:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
   ...
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, ...)
   ...
```

template:

```
{{ request.user.profile }}
```